# Algorithm 13x13 Matrix String

Tags: algorithm, matrix

```
String[] Table = new String[13];

Table[0] = "A";
Table[1] = "K";
Table[2] = "Q";
Table[3] = "J";
Table[4] = "T";
Table[5] = "9";
Table[6] = "8";
Table[7] = "7";
Table[8] = "6";
Table[9] = "5";
Table[10] = "4";
Table[11] = "3";
Table[12] = "2";

    for(int i = 0; i < 13;i++) {
    System.out.println("\n");
    for (int y = 0; y < 13;y++) {


        System.out.print("[" + Table[i]  + Table[y] + "]");

    }
  }
 }

[AA][AK][AQ][AJ][AT][A9][A8][A7][A6][A5][A4][A3][A2]

[KA][KK][KQ][KJ][KT][K9][K8][K7][K6][K5][K4][K3][K2]

[QA][QK][QQ][QJ][QT][Q9][Q8][Q7][Q6][Q5][Q4][Q3][Q2]

[JA][JK][JQ][JJ][JT][J9][J8][J7][J6][J5][J4][J3][J2]

[TA][TK][TQ][TJ][TT][T9][T8][T7][T6][T5][T4][T3][T2]

[9A][9K][9Q][9J][9T][99][98][97][96][95][94][93][92]

[8A][8K][8Q][8J][8T][89][88][87][86][85][84][83][82]

[7A][7K][7Q][7J][7T][79][78][77][76][75][74][73][72]

[6A][6K][6Q][6J][6T][69][68][67][66][65][64][63][62]

[5A][5K][5Q][5J][5T][59][58][57][56][55][54][53][52]

[4A][4K][4Q][4J][4T][49][48][47][46][45][44][43][42]

[3A][3K][3Q][3J][3T][39][38][37][36][35][34][33][32]
[2A][2K][2Q][2J][2T][29][28][27][26][25][24][23][22]
```

Have a look at this matrix, first row is fine as you see.
But after every row i would like to print biggest value of card first.
As you see its increasing with 1+ hand every every row but we also need to switch back and print hands like the first ones.. depending what value the hands got. . . . . .. .

well i think the matrix explain this better than me :)

Comment: An `if` statement should do it. `if (i < y)` then print `Table[i]` first, otherwise print `Table[y]` first.

Comment: Thank you , how could i miss that? so simple :)  + else for the pairs